# can't debug hanging $.post in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing this extension https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1022928/latest/

The code central to this question is in Data/panel.js

And it's working pretty well, except that whenever I hit "Gem" to post a jquery call, it just hangs at the loading icon, I don't get any feedback in the console as to why the call is not going through and being processed as it should.

So how do I debug that with the new firefox add-on sdk builder beta. I've tried writing to console.log(), and I've read that it's supposed to work for others, but I really can't see any of my log messages, just errors that are synchronous in code, and hence not ajax errors.

Returning to my question: How do I debug a hanging ajax call in my firefox extension's panel?

Comment: When I install your app with the addon builder I see no icon. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @lc2817 - thank you for your reply. The icon may be a little hard to see because it's grey (I'm going to change that at some point), it's not in the toolbar but in the widgets panel at the bottom of the window. Are you certain nothing appears?

Comment: @lc2817 - and of course you need firefox and the add-on installer extension installed :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with pointing to a site where one can try the extension, but it is generally a good idea to also post the relevant code here. Getting a response might take a while if people first have to dig through your code on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTPFox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/httpfox/) shows that your request was sent successfully and result is a `500 Internal Error` response. So jQuery would have called an error callback - but you didn't give it any (see [`jQuery.post()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), the third parameter is the *success* callback). To define an error callback you should ideally use [`jQuery.ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST"
  url: url,
  data {title:$("#txtTitle").val(), url:encodeURIComponent(taburl)},
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
    ...
  },
  error: function(data, textStatus) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Or you could use the [`request` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html) of the Add-on SDK that provides similar API.

To sum up: you don't see an error message because there was no error. In case of errors you should indeed expect an exception that will be visible in Error Console if not caught.

Comment: thank you for your answer I'm aware that you have actually answered my question, but I just wanted to ask if you have any idea why this 500 is being thrown - I'm pretty sure it's firefox specific, as I've made a similar extension in chrome and safari, and it works with no errors.

Comment: @Jakob: That should be a separate question and depends on what you have on the server side. But you should check the server logs first.