# firefox ajax call returning NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI or jsonp false error

Tags: javascript, firefox, jquery, firefox-addon

In relation to [can't debug hanging $.post in firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949099/cant-debug-hanging-post-in-firefox-extension/7954947)

can anyone tell me why my extension https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1022928/latest/ is with this ajax call:

```
var url = 'http://e-ønsker.dk/wishlist/ajax/add/';
$(this).hide();
//show icon loading
$("#icon").show();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {title:$("#txtTitle").val(), url:encodeURIComponent(taburl)},
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if(data.code > 0)
    {
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('accept');
    }
    else
    {
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
    if(data.code == '-1')
        alert('kunne ikke finde din ønskeseddel på e-ønsker.dk - besøg e-ønsker.dk, og prøv derefter igen');
    }
  },
  error: function(data, textStatus) {
      alert(textStatus);
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
  }
});
```

is returning the error NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI. HttpFox says it's a 500 error which would indicate an internal error, but this exact call works from both chrome and safari in their extensions, so I'm suspecting the error to be related to firefox specifically.

**UPDATE**

So I added `dataType: "jsonp"` and that did some of the magic, now I get a 200 response, but I still get a parsererror.

Weirdest thing is that after I modify my server to accomodate JSONP jquery chooses the error method, and the xhr.statusText that I show here `alert(xhr.statusText);` gives me an alert with the statustext "success" why won't jquery choose the success method when it actually works??

Comment: are you sure about `jsonp`? try `json`

Comment: Definitely a problem with the letter "ø" in your URL - wrong file encoding?

Comment: @3nigma - json gave me the NS_ERROR_DOm_BAD_URI error

Comment: @WladimirPalant - are you 100% ? It's a danish url I changed it to it's synonym domain name, but that still gave me a parsererror

Comment: Can you see the data being send and received in firebug ?

Comment: @ManseUK I can see the data being sent, not recieved, buit the return data is formed as json and not jsonp, so I would actually prefer to solve the initial problem instead of having to format the response as jsonp, but maybe it's not possible due to firefox security restrictions. It's just odd to me that all other browsers can handle this then.

Comment: All browsers are limited to the Same Origin Policy (ie CANNOT get AJAX content from a different domain - i suspect what is happening is that the domain name is being encoded in firefox and looks different - have you tried using a relative path

Comment: it's from an extension, so it actually is not from the same domain. I'm going to make a check serverside whether the callback has been set, and if so to format the response as jsonp and not json. What mystifies me is that this behaviour is firefox specific. Neither safari nor chrome extensions exibit this restricting behaviour and they should have seperate origin according to my belief aswell, but they must not have I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get data from a different domain from the one you are currently on using AJAX -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If you are using the same domain then use relative paths ... I suspect that Firefox is encoding the `e-ønsker.dk` part of the url - making it look like a different domain.

Comment: @3nigma When i enter `http://e-ønsker.dk/wishlist/ajax/add/` into my browser (chrome) it gets changed to `http://xn--e-nsker-r1a.dk/wishlist/ajax/add/` on Firefox this change doesnt happen ... but it may well do when using ajax - i suggested using relative paths to remove the issue of the name change / encoding .....