# POST AJAX request denied - CORS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post, cors

I have setup CORS on my node.js server on port 5000 as follows:

```
var app = express();

app.use(cors()); //normal CORS
app.options('*', cors()); //preflight 

app.post('/connect', function(req, res) { 
    console.log("Connection request received !")
});

var port = 5000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port '+port);
});
```

I am now trying to send AJAX POST requests using JQuery like so, in a static web page open from my hard disk :

```
var xhr = $.post({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/connect',
            complete: function() {
                console.log("done !")
            },
            crossDomain: true
        });

xhr.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
    alert(error)
})
```

The `complete` function is never called, and the only alert I get is an alert from the XHR `fail` handler, containing the following error :

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

I think CORS is well-configured, **what am I missing ?**

---

*EDIT* : for those in my case, the best solution I could find was to send the page from the server :

```
app.use(express.static('web'))

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/web/HTML/index.html');
});
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar  This question is NOT a duplicate of this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969265. The accepted answer there is to enable CORS to prevent problems with Cross-origin policy, which I did. Please try not to mark as duplicate too quickly.

Comment: Reopened it. Looks like a problem with the NodeJS stuff... Let's see if NodeJS folks answer it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Do you by "in a static web page open from my hard disk" mean that the file is loaded using the `file://` protocol?

Comment: @Philip absolutely

Comment: The issue definitively is that CORS does not work correctly. But I cannot reproduce the error, your example works fine here (with the versions of expressjs and cors that npm current installs).

Comment: For info, my browser is firefox ESR 45.2.0 maybe this is where the problem comes from ?

Comment: have you tried a package  addon like this one https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code I am using.  It is located in my app.js file

```
app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer because, even though it doesn't directly solve the problem, it gives a good workaround until the `cors` module gets fixed. Also, the code is cleaner than @TimothyMoody's.Thank you !

Comment: The `if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS')` saved me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used cors() so I can't speak to that piece. But you could manually allow cross origin resource sharing by setting up the node.js headers.

Add This Pre-Route on All Requests

```
app.route('*')
   .all(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-API-TOKEN, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-Wit
h');
   next();
})
```

This should work.

Comment: Clever solution, I will definitely try it

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that use cors.

The **node** code used is just:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

/* Connect/other routes here */
```

The **jquery** code look a litte different:

```
$.post('http://localhost:5000/connect', {}).done( () => {
  // Request complete
}).fail((jqXHR) => {
  // Request failed 
});
```

Comment: This is almost exactly equivalent to my code, except you don't enable pre-flight requests, and I don't use the `done` xhr callback ...

Answer (score 0):

CORS doesn't work using the `file` protocol because there is no server there to send back the requisite headers. Your solution of using a server is the only way to get CORS to work.

Comment: I want the server to send me the headers when AJAXing, not when loading the page, that's not how it works. When AJAXing, there is indeed a server which should send me the headers and it should be sufficient

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that a page on the `file` protocol doesn't have a hostname to send in the Ajax request, so the responding server can't validate whether it matches the CORS access rules.