# reponse is empty in client side in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am able to see the response in post man but when i checked in network with client side i am getting 200 ok but i am not getting any response.I think it may be because of CORS.Can some one suggest me help.
my js,
I am sending users/1 from my client side but i am not even getting the param1 to my function in backend

```
    var express = require('express');


    var router = express.Router();
     var mysql     =    require('mysql');
    var app = express();
     var cors = require('cors')
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });
     var connection      =    mysql.createConnection({
         // connectionLimit : 100, //important
         host     : 'localhost',
         user     : 'root',
         password : 'root',
         database : 'socialwiki'
     });
     connection.connect(function(error){
      if(!!error){
        console.log('error');

      }else{
        console.log('connected');
      }
    });
    exports.getlist = function( req, res ) {
      console.log(req.id);
     connection.query("SELECT * FROM profile",function(error,result,rows,fields){
        if(!!error){
            console.log('fail');
        }else{
          console.log(result);
          res.send(result);
        }
      // }

      });}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. Decide what indentation you want to use (e.g. 2 spaces? 4 spaces?) and then indent it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CORS in the problem you could use the node module [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450395/1319519) is a example on how to configure cors with express!

Comment: Thank you joakim,i need to use same method for post also?

Answer (score 0):

replace the above code with below to allow cross-request the

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,x-access-token,content-type,Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
var connection      =    mysql.createConnection({
  // connectionLimit : 100, //important
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'socialwiki'
});
connection.connect(function(error){
  if(!!error){
    console.log('error');

  }else{
    console.log('connected');
  }
});
exports.getlist = function( req, res ) {
  console.log(req.id);
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM profile",function(error,result,rows,fields){
    if(!!error){
      console.log('fail');
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Supraj,nothing changed with the replacement

Comment: can you try the changes