# CORS policy blocking HTTP delete method

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I have been working on [this open](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-ocl-client) source project for some time now and I encountered an issue where CORS policy is blocking the HTTP delete method whenever I make an axios call. Currently, I do not have access to the backend and when I checked the CORS configuration [here](https://github.com/OpenConceptLab/oclapi/blob/master/ocl/oclapi/settings/common.py) (Django config file), all looks good to me. Can you maybe take a look at the config file and advise me where necessary. Below is a snippet of the CORS error I get.
[image]

Comment: Hi, you can check out my answer here. [How to fix CORS - in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364076/post-ajax-request-denied-cors/39513718#39513718)

Answer (score 2):

1. If it does not work after adding `Delete` in `setHeader`, you need to restart your server.
2. Your Route could have little mistake. like missing `/`.

Sometimes it's stuck even after updating the source code.

```
res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
```

Comment: Great idea with the second point. I did encounter this error because I did not format my payload well, and then the delete request of a specific id couldn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

While using axios, in order to allow cross domain access, set header `crossDomain:true` and provide an object containing the headers as the last argument.

Your axios request would be like:-

```
var heads={ crossDomain: true, "Content-Type": "application/json" }

axios.post(API,data, {headers:heads})
```